# iOS: This app was built with the iOS 11.4 SDK

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm getting this warning when I'm uploading the app into the App Store:

> This app was built with the iOS 11.4 SDK. Starting March 2019, all iOS
>   apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 12.1 SDK or
>   later, included in Xcode 10.1 or later.

Well, this is not true. I'm using Xcode 10.2, the code is written in ObjectiveC, and according my terminal:

```
~ xcodebuild -sdk -version

iPhoneOS12.2.sdk - iOS 12.2 (iphoneos12.2)
SDKVersion: 12.2
```

I have just one xcode installed, and the Command Line Tools is the 10.2.

And as you can see the base sdk is set to "iOS"

[image]

And there are not other selections:

[image]

What do you think could be the problem? Could be the minimum iOS Target currently set to 8?

The App builds fine in the new iphone's simulators

Comment: Any chance you have cocoapods or carthage inclusions that specify a different iOS SDK in their podfile/cartfile? If not that, do you include any precompiled libraries that were built with a different version of Xcode?

Your deploy target (iOS 8) has nothing to do with this error.

Comment: Have you checked the command line tools in xcode-preferrences -> locations?